# Writing exotic (non-ascii) characters to Oracle DB using pandas.to_sql in Python 3.6

Tags: python, oracle, pandas, encoding

I'm having difficulty writing values from a `pandas.DataFrame` which contain non-ASCII characters to an Oracle data base. Here is a reproducible example (given an real connection string):

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Unicode, NVARCHAR

connection_string = oracle://<name>:<password>@<database>'

df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['Société Générale']
    ], columns=['firm'])

conn = create_engine(connection_string, encoding='utf-8')
dtypes = {'firm': Unicode(40)}

df.to_sql('test', con=connection_string, dtype=dtypes, if_exists='replace')
```

The error produced looks like

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I guess the question is how do I get it to use UTF-8 encoding when writing. I know the default value for `encoding` in `create_engine` is `utf-8'` and I thought it would control the encoding used. 
I've also tried `dtypes = {'firm': NVARCHAR(40, convert_unicode=True)}` but get the same error.

I tried encoding the data before writing (`df['firm'] = df.firms.str.encode('utf-8')`) which does get around this problem only to lead to bigger problems.

This seems like a straightforward problem but I've spent hours looking at the docs and SO and can't figure out what to do.

Versions used are; `Python: 3.6`, `pandas: 0.20`, `sqlalchemy: 1.11`

Comment: What do you get when you query the data directly via SQL? Try also `DUMP(firm, 1016)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm actually creating a table from scratch so there is nothing to query...

Comment: And what do you get when you query the table after you have insert something? Don't say"The data is deleted afterwards." - Then I would ask you: "Why do you store the data in database at all?"

Comment: And if you try print(sys.getdefaultencoding()) ? does it say utf-8?

Comment: @Uvar Yes, utf-8 is the default encoding.

Comment: @JoeCondron interested to know  if you found a workaround for this

Comment: @DACW yes, I moved onto a different project :) Unfortunately, I didn't find a satisfactory workaround; I just used string methods to replace the exotic characters with their closest representation (`é -> e`, for example).

Comment: @DACW Take a look if my solution works for you.

Answer (score 4):

It is old question but I have struggled with same issue recently, and found a solution that worked for me.

I had to set

```
os.environ['NLS_LANG'] = ".AL32UTF8"
```

And it worked for me. However I found that inserting data is very slow.